# How to insert only one row which is going to update

Tags: mysql, trigger

I want to fire a trigger in Mysql DB before update the row. And I want to insert the entire row value in another table.

My trigger fires, but the problem is, it inserts all the data from old table to new one.

My query is: How can I activate the trigger for particular id in old table?

I've tried the various links but they are not useful for me.

My attempt:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` TRIGGER before_trn_student_profile_update 
    BEFORE UPDATE ON trn_student_profile
    FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO trn_student_profile_history (
`StudentID`,
`SchoolID`,
`SessionID`,
`ClassID`,
`SectionID`,
`AdmissionDate`,
`AdmissionNumber`,
`ReferenceNo`,
`StudentTypeID`,
`StudentName`,
`FatherTitle`,
`FatherName`,
`IsFatherGuardian`,
`MotherTitle`,
`MotherName`,
`parent_address`,
`DateOfBirth`,
`Gender`,
`SocialCategoryID`,
`ReligionID`,
`MotherToungeID`,
`LocalityName`,
`BelongToBPL`,
`BelongToDisadvantageGroup`,
`IsBelongToDisadvantageGroup`,
`IsFreeEduction`,
`PreviousYearClassID`,
`PreviousYearStatusID`,
`PreviousYearAttendanceDays`,
`MeduimOfInstructionID`,
`DisabilityTypeID`,
`IsLastExaminationAppeared`,
`IsLastExaminationPassed`,
`LastExaminationPercentage`,
`SchoolingStatusID`,
`StreamID`,
`CWSANFacilityID`,
`UniformSetID`,
`IsFreeTextBooks`,
`IsFreeTransport`,
`IsFreeEscortFacility`,
`IsMDMBenificiary`,
`FreeHostelFacilityID`,
`SpecialTraining`,
`IsFolicAcidTabletReceived`,
`IsDewormingTablets`,
`IsVitaminASupplement`,
`VocationCourseTradeID`,
`JobRoleID`,
`NSFQLevelID`,
`StudentOpted`,
`PlacementStatus`,
`SalaryOffered`,
`BankAccountNumber`,
`BranchIFSCCode`,
`MobileNumber`,
`Email`,
`IsActive`,
`P1Status`,
`P2Status`,
`DataStatus`,
`CreatedByUserID`,
`CreatedDate`,
`UpdatedByUserID`,
`UpdatedDate`,
`IsChildHomeless`,
`GradeOptedForVocationalCourse`,
`SocialCatagoryOther`,
`ReligionOther`,
`MotherTongueOther`,
`MediumOfInstructionOther`,
`TypeOfDisabilityOther`,
`SchoolingStatusOther`,
`StreamOther`,
`VocationCourseTradeOther`,
`cswnOther`,
`Reason`,
`EnrolmentType`,
`IsVocationalRequired`,
`unique_id`,
`virtual_id`,
`enrollment_id`,
`unique_student_number`,
`reason_id_for_not_having_adhar`,
`student_first_name`,
`student_middle_name`,
`student_last_name`,
`student_subCategory_Id`,
`prior_status_id`,
`state_id`,
`district_id`,
`block_id`,
`habitation_id`,
`student_Opted_Id`,
`action_status`)
select 
`StudentID`,
`SchoolID`,
`SessionID`,
`ClassID`,
`SectionID`,
`AdmissionDate`,
`AdmissionNumber`,
`ReferenceNo`,
`StudentTypeID`,
`StudentName`,
`FatherTitle`,
`FatherName`,
`IsFatherGuardian`,
`MotherTitle`,
`MotherName`,
`parent_address`,
`DateOfBirth`,
`Gender`,
`SocialCategoryID`,
`ReligionID`,
`MotherToungeID`,
`LocalityName`,
`BelongToBPL`,
`BelongToDisadvantageGroup`,
`IsBelongToDisadvantageGroup`,
`IsFreeEduction`,
`PreviousYearClassID`,
`PreviousYearStatusID`,
`PreviousYearAttendanceDays`,
`MeduimOfInstructionID`,
`DisabilityTypeID`,
`IsLastExaminationAppeared`,
`IsLastExaminationPassed`,
`LastExaminationPercentage`,
`SchoolingStatusID`,
`StreamID`,
`CWSANFacilityID`,
`UniformSetID`,
`IsFreeTextBooks`,
`IsFreeTransport`,
`IsFreeEscortFacility`,
`IsMDMBenificiary`,
`FreeHostelFacilityID`,
`SpecialTraining`,
`IsFolicAcidTabletReceived`,
`IsDewormingTablets`,
`IsVitaminASupplement`,
`VocationCourseTradeID`,
`JobRoleID`,
`NSFQLevelID`,
`StudentOpted`,
`PlacementStatus`,
`SalaryOffered`,
`BankAccountNumber`,
`BranchIFSCCode`,
`MobileNumber`,
`Email`,
`IsActive`,
`P1Status`,
`P2Status`,
`DataStatus`,
`CreatedByUserID`,
`CreatedDate`,
`UpdatedByUserID`,
`UpdatedDate`,
`IsChildHomeless`,
`GradeOptedForVocationalCourse`,
`SocialCatagoryOther`,
`ReligionOther`,
`MotherTongueOther`,
`MediumOfInstructionOther`,
`TypeOfDisabilityOther`,
`SchoolingStatusOther`,
`StreamOther`,
`VocationCourseTradeOther`,
`cswnOther`,
`Reason`,
`EnrolmentType`,
`IsVocationalRequired`,
`unique_id`,
`virtual_id`,
`enrollment_id`,
`unique_student_number`,
`reason_id_for_not_having_adhar`,
`student_first_name`,
`student_middle_name`,
`student_last_name`,
`student_subCategory_Id`,
`prior_status_id`,
`state_id`,
`district_id`,
`block_id`,
`habitation_id`,
`student_Opted_Id`,
`action_status` '1' from trn_student_profile
 where trn_student_profile.StudentID != NEW.StudentID AND trn_student_profile.SchoolID != NEW.SchoolID; 
END
```

Thanks,

Comment: I have figured out the solution for the issue. I was just needed to get the id like `NEW.StudentID`

Comment: You can answer your own question :-) - no points though :-(

Answer (score 0):

> And I want to insert the entire row value in another table.

Be more precise -- which "row value" are you referring to?  Assuming you want to copy the before-update values from `profile` to `profile_history`, then:

```
from trn_student_profile
where trn_student_profile.StudentID != NEW.StudentID
  AND trn_student_profile.SchoolID != NEW.SchoolID;
```

-->

```
from OLD
where OLD.StudentID != NEW.StudentID
  AND OLD.SchoolID  != NEW.SchoolID;
```

And... Perhaps you want `OR` instead of `AND`?